# Get order items (products) by Order number

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Here I show how to get items from a Order by the order number id:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order_id);
$items = $order->getAllItems();
$itemcount = count($items);
$name = array();
$unitPrice = array();
$sku = array();
$ids = array();
$qty = array();
foreach ($items as $itemId => $item) {
    $name[] = $item->getName();
    $unitPrice[] = $item->getPrice();
    $sku[] = $item->getSku();
    $ids[] = $item->getProductId();
    $qty[] = $item->getQtyToInvoice();
}
```

How can I do the same but in SQL, get all the items information (name, price, image..) by order number id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use sql query like :

This is for select item name and data

```
select sales_flat_order.entity_id,sales_flat_order.increment_id,sales_flat_order_item.item_id, sales_flat_order_item.sku, sales_flat_order_item.name from sales_flat_order right join sales_flat_order_item on sales_flat_order.entity_id = sales_flat_order_item.order_id where increment_id = 100000042
```

Comment: thanks, can you tell me how to get the image fof the product (url)?

Answer (score 2):

// getSelect() method allowed for order collection only so you can print query for specific order as as below.

```
$order_id = 12345;
$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
  ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
  ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $order_id);
echo $orders->getSelect();
```

Comment: SQL that i needed

Comment: @MarcoSantos `echo $orders->getSelect();` gives you the SQL query (just has to be cast to string ... `echo (string) $orders->getSelect()` or `echo $orders->getSelect()->__toString()`